# 2sxc Prefill datetime value in Manage Content Data

Tags: 2sxc

I created a Entity in Content-Types and Data and this entity have a field that is a datetime

When I click in the Plus button (+) I want to hide the field from user (this I got) and that default value be the current date (to be filled behind the scene)

Is there a way to achieve this ?

I read about prefill but I dont got how to do that with the default "Manage Content / Data"

I´m using 2sxc 10.24.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, @Alexandre ;)

The special buttons can only be done in the view. The internal manage-data doesn't provide options to customize. You can set default texts, but there is currently no mechanism to provide tokens, JS or something to get dynamic values as an initial value from the normal Admin-dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

I got if I create a view and then use

```
@Edit.Toolbar(toolbar: new object[] { new { command = new { action = "new", contentType = "Articles", prefill = new { CreationDate = DateTime.Now } }}}
```

I believe that to do that in Manage Content / Data will be need to modify the "view" from the 2sxc